# Git (LFS) fails because "LFS: Put" is forbidden

Tags: github, git-lfs

I want to push some changes to my own git LFS repository on GitHub, which is a fork of another project, but when I try to do that, I get an error

```
> git push origin develop-imb:develop-imb
LFS: Put "https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/alambic/media/somepath": Forbidden
LFS: Put "https://github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/alambic/media/someotherpath": Forbidden
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/nicolazilio/parkour-imb-mainz.git'
```

Does anybody have any clue as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Even after a fork, LFS would be pushed to the original repo's assigned Content Delivery Network. You're not able to push LFS objects because there's a quota on the original public repo that would otherwise be vulnerable to abuse attacks. This is a safety measure on GitHub.com

The only "solutions" that I could think of are rather limited:

- Use `git lfs untrack`, and try pushing these to your own fork without LFS. Optionally, you could install lfs on the fork, re-track them before pushing, and start using your own quota. This may be desirable on hard forks (e.g. not contributing back to upstream)
- Ask to have write permission on the original public repo, if that's possible.
- Ask the original public repo to stop using LFS.

See [What is the workflow for Git LFS with forks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359067/what-is-the-workflow-for-git-lfs-with-forks) for another proposed answer. Even if they're speaking of Bitbucket, the same workflow would probably apply.